# Groovy: Iterating a list

Tags: list, sorting, random, groovy

I was trying to iterate a list and after googling, I found one solution like below:

```
value([0,1,2,3,4,5,6].sort{new Random()}?.take(1)[0])
```

I did not understand this part: 
    sort{new Random()}

Can someone explain this?
And which class the take method is belonging to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy: How Closure works in sort()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508260/groovy-how-closure-works-in-sort)

Comment: It seems to me that the `Random` class is NOT being used effectively. The class itself is not `Comparable`, nor does Groovy define any default coercions for the class (other than what is already defined for `Object`). So the sort value is at the mercy of Groovy's generated comparator, which, having no other way to compare the objects, ends up comparing their hash codes. This certainly would ensure some randomness in the outcome, but no more so than if the sort closure had been `{new Object()}`.

Comment: In any case, the original programmer probably intended to shuffle the list, and their code does that does that, but hardly in an efficient way. The shuffling is also not reproducible, which would be an advantage of using the features of the `Random` class, if the original programmer had been inclined to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sort`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure)) receives a closure to determine the order that you wish. In this example, it makes a random sort.

`take` comes from [`Iterable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#take(int)) and returns the first n elements.

Comment: Can you please give a little mor explanation on how this clouser is being used in the sort method?I mean how the Random object is being used  for sorting integers?

Comment: It's not sorting, it's randomly shuffling

Comment: @tim_yates: OK. Can you please explain how  a Random class object is being used to shuffle? I mean how this clouser is being invoked?