# Groovy: How Closure works in sort()

Tags: list, sorting, groovy

I found a code segment like:

```
def l1 = ["hello","hi","hey"]    
l1.sort{new Random()}
```

I could not figure out how a Random class object is being usd to sort/shuffle the list items? How Random class object is returning Comparable/Comparator object to perform operation?

In the groovy doc, I found the statement:
Sorts this Iterable using the given Closure to determine the correct ordering.
But how Random is used here?

Comment: Could not understand how Random class is being used in the same way like sort { it.length() }   or   sort { a, b -> a.length() <=> b.length() }   which really have meaning.

Comment: It seems to me that the `Random` class is NOT being used effectively. The class itself is not `Comparable`, nor does Groovy define any default coercions for the class (other than what is already defined for `Object`). So the sort value is whatever `Comparable` type the newly-created `Random` object can be coerced into (probably `String`). This certainly would ensure *some* randomness in the outcome, but no more so than if the sort closure had been `{new Object()}`. In any case, the person who wrote this probably intended to shuffle the list, and it does that, but hardly in an efficient way.

Comment: Nope, `String` was a bad guess. Since it can't figure out any legitimate way to compare two different `Random` objects, Groovy's generated comparator compares the two `Random` objects' hash codes. Again, this is a really kludgy and inefficient way to get random behavior, and, since it does not actually use the pseudo-randomness features of the `Random` class, there is no reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the intent here is that a random value is used as the `Comparable` for each entry (i.e. using the single-argument closure variant of [`Iterable.sort(Closure closure)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)).  It is these random values that are being compared, and thus dictating the sort order.  Thus this leads to a randomised sort order.

However, I'm not convinced this leads to well-defined behaviour.  The documentation does not define whether:

1. The closure is evaluated precisely once for each element of the iterable.
2. How `sort` should respond to inconsistent `Comparable` values.

If #1 is not true, then inconsistent values would get generated - it's unclear whether that would cause the `sort` implementation to do wacky things.

Comment: As to #1, a quick look at the Groovy and Java (Oracle) code shows that the closure is evaluated over and over again. As to #2, in both the MergeSort algrithm and the TimSort algorithm each comparison is always in pursuit of narrowing the sort, so there should be no indefinite looping. However, the sort path (and hence results) are never reproducible, to say the least.